# completion event of crawling all of the sub URLs for specific base URL in Storm Crawler

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am currently working on Storm Crawler based project. I need to do some processing after the completion event of the crawling of all sub URLs for that base URL. For example, I want to change a status when all of the discovered URLs for that domain crawled successfully or with an error. How can I find a finishing event for each Base URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, no. you would have to implement a mechanism to check whether there are unfetched URLs left for a given key yourself.

Comment: I have implemented a scheduler job in java for counting number of discovered URLs for each base URL. if the count is zero then I conduct the finishing event for that base URL.Is it a true approach?